# Visual Studio slow in Virtualbox

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, virtualization, virtualbox

Like really really slow.

I've got a 64 bit, 8 cores, 12 gig ram windows 7 host.  I gave 4 cores and 4 gigs of ram to a 64 bit windows 7 virtual machine within which I am trying to run visual studio 2010 (and sql server - but that's it).

It worked for a few days but then the resource usage went off the charts - near 100% CPU at all times.  I turned off windows 7 visual effects and it dropped immediately to normal levels.  However any time I try to do anything in visual studio it spikes right back up.

Does anyone with a similar rig have a similar experience?  I know people have pulled this set-up off successfully and have been very happy with it so I'm wondering if I just have a bad configuration somewhere.

Comment: I have the same machine and the same problem. I've found the VM starts getting slower and slower with time so I restart it often - it helps for a while. Does not matter if I use one or more cores.

Comment: This happens to me too on this machine.  On my much slower laptop it does not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Found a clue here](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=26611).

It would seem that virtualbox 3.1.4 (my current version) freaks out when you tell it to use more than one CPU on windows 7.  I set it to use 1 CPU instead of 4 and resource usage went back to normal.

Hope they fix this soon.

Comment: To be fair, its still insanely slow.  Just better

Comment: This made a big difference. Windows 7 on OS X Yosemite / Virtual Box / Visual Studio Express 2013. 4 cores -> 1.

Answer (score 15):

Visual Studio 2010 uses GPU acceleration to do its GUI because it uses WPF for its forms. VM's don't pass through GPU tasks all that efficiently. In VS goto Tools -> Options -> Environment -> General -> Visual experience and uncheck the 3 check boxes in that fieldset and see if that does the trick.

I've found VM's will sometimes work fine with Aero and VS 2010 using the GPU but then for no reason started doing exactly what you describe. This works for me.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. all checkboxes unchecked but still having problems. Any other advice?

Comment: No :( that's always done it for me albeit I'm usually using Parallels or VMware Fusion since I use OS X as host. What VM software are you using?

Comment: My W7 VM client has all 4 cores turned on at 100%, 2D acceleration on. Uncheck the 3 check boxes under Visual experience works wonders for me - even faster than my "real" machine at work.

Answer (score 4):

Disabling 3D acceleration under VM settings did the trick for me.

Answer (score 4):

My current settings are:

- disabled 3D acceleration
- disabled Remote Display Server
- only 1 CPU

The VS 2010 speed is not excelent but also not so slow.

Comment: When installing VS2013, the installation ran terribly slow.  In addition to the above, I also set my VM memory to 6 GB; that seemed to fix the issue I eas experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

This issue might be because of the DPC latency issue:

https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/6242

Either upgrade to v4.3.4 or disable the VT-x in your BIOS